# How do I get dapper to map an int to a boolean property

Tags: .net, dapper

I have this class...

```
public class MyDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

and then use dapper to attempt to create a list like this...

```
            var list = this.db.OpenConnection().Query<MyDTO>(
            @"SELECT T1.id, T2.id IS NOT NULL AS selected
            FROM     table1 T1
            LEFT
            JOIN     table2 T2 
            ON   T2.id = T1.id
            AND  Tl.id = @Id",
            new { Id = id });
```

which returns a result set like this....

```
id  selected
 9         0
10         1
11         1
12         0
```

But when code above is executed, i get an error

```
[InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.]
Deserialize3d3c9260-abcb-4964-97c1-4a4e66b786d3(IDataReader ) +354

[DataException: Error parsing column 2 (selected=0 - Int64)]
Dapper.SqlMapper.ThrowDataException(Exception ex, Int32 index, IDataReader reader) in     C:\Projects\Web\SqlMapper.cs:1685
Deserialize3d3c9260-abcb-4964-97c1-4a4e66b786d3(IDataReader ) +432
Dapper.<QueryInternal>d__13`1.MoveNext() in C:\Projects\Web\Source\SqlMapper.cs:608
System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +327
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
Dapper.SqlMapper.Query(IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) in C:\Projects\Web\Source\SqlMapper.cs:538
```

I'm going to create a "Translating" property for now, but is this an unusual use case?

Comment: How do your tables look like, and what OS version are you running with? I tested the above code on my system and could map an int value to a boolean without problems using dapper.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it should do the trick:

```
SELECT T1.id, CAST(CASE WHEN T2.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS BIT) AS selected
FROM ...
```

(To be honest, I'm not convinced that your `T2.id IS NOT NULL AS selected` clause is legal T-SQL in the first place, but if you say that it's working then I'll take your word for it!)

Comment: Old but gold. thanks for that.